# Why does foo = function() run the function in Python?

Tags: python, function, variables

I'm up to Exercise 41 in Learn Python the Hard Way, and I'm having a really hard time wrapping my brain around the fact that the entire thing hinges on a function running just because it's been assigned as a value to a variable. I wrote up a little script to confirm that this is how it works, and it does:

```
def pants():
    print "Put on some pants!"

def shorts():
    print "And don't forget your underwear!"

zap = pants()
thing = shorts()
```

With the results being:

```
Put on some pants!
And don't forget your underwear!
```

So obviously this happens, but I can't understand why the language works that way -- what the logic is behind the language that makes this a valuable way of operating. I think it'd be helpful for me moving forward to understand *why* this is, rather than just "that's the way it works."

For clarity: I'm asking (I guess) why the function is running, when all I'm doing is assigning it as a value for something. The print statements are just there so I can see that the function is indeed running.

It's the fact that I'm not ever actually running

pants()
shorts()

that is confusing me.

To create a tortured analogy, if me-baking-cookies-at-home were "cookies()", and I were to make cookies on Saturdays, I might eventually believe that

Saturday = cookies()

but just thinking "hey, Saturday is cookie day" is not the same as *actually baking cookies*... so why does just saying

Saturday = cookies()

actually bake the cookies, rather than just setting up Saturday with the variable "cookies()" for some later use?

Comment: You're probably confusing `print` with `return`.

Comment: I think Juhana might be right. Are you expecting `zap` to have a value of "Put on some pants!"? If so then change the `print` to a `return` and then `print zap` after it's been assigned.

Comment: Yes, clearly your expectations are misaligned with the language. What were you expecting?

Comment: What would be a more intuitive way for it to work?

Comment: Are you asking why the functions are being called, or why you're getting output on the screen? Please clarify.

Comment: I've attempted to clarify above. Not understanding something occasionally makes it difficult to understand what you're not understanding, but hopefully the "cookies" analogy makes it more clear what I'm hung up on.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

When you use the parentheses `()` the function gets called. If you want to assign the function to the variable to reuse it you should remove there parentheses.

Example:

```
def pants():
    print "Put on some pants!"

def shorts():
    print "And don't forget your underwear!"

zap = pants
thing = shorts
```

And then when you want to call those functions:

```
zap()
thing()
```

Comment: So the presence of () “converts” things into functions in Python's eyes, and Python attempts to run those functions immediately to get their return value?

Comment: No, what "converts" them into functions is when you declare them. In Python everything is an object. A function is a "callable" object. As an object you can assign it to a variable, to another object as a property, pass it as a parameter, etc. Then when you **call** it, it executes its procedure. For more detailed information, I'd suggest you read about Python's [data model](http://docs.python.org/reference/datamodel.html).

Comment: Adding to my previous comment: the presence of `()` tells Python to **call** the object. If its a function it will be executed, if it's not, it will raise an exception stating that the object is not callable. Whether the function returns something or not is up to you and what you need to do. If you want to assign the result of a function to a variable, then you need to use `return` as it was pointed out in the other answers. If you just want to print something out, you can use `print` and don't need to return anything.

Answer (score 6):

> So obviously this happens, but I can't understand why the language works that way -- what the logic is behind the language that makes this a valuable way of operating. I think it'd be helpful for me moving forward to understand why this is, rather than just "that's the way it works."

The language needs some way to distinguish between the function and the act of calling the function. That is what the parentheses provide.

```
f = foo
```

Now `f` is bound to the function itself. The function `foo` could be executed by `f()`.

```
f = foo()
```

This calls the function `foo` and binds the return value to `f`.

Note that whether or not you bind the return value to a name is irrelevant. Simply writing

```
foo()
```

will also execute the function but the return value will simply be ignored.

Comment: So, if I'm understanding correctly, Python will attempt to execute anything with () after it as a function, regardless of most contexts its in -- using the return value of the function in place of function() if the function is something that is supposed to represent a variable in its current context?

Answer (score 5):

Although it may seem like your functions don't return anything, they do in fact. Quoting [the Python.org documentation](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/controlflow.html#defining-functions):

> The return statement returns with a value from a function. return without an expression argument returns None. Falling off the end of a function also returns None.

So your functions really look like this:

```
def pants():
    print "Put on some pants!"
    return None

def shorts():
    print "And don't forget your underwear!"
    return None
```

Your assignments assign to `zap` whatever `pants` returns (i.e. the value of `pants()`), and to `thing` whatever `shorts` returns. In your case, both are `None`, but of course the functions must be run in order to figure this out(*). Afterall, it could be that `pants` returns `42` during leap years, and that `shorts` returns `'Foobar'` whenever some random number generator "rolls" a 6.

---

(*) Digression: That the functions "must be run" should not be considered universally true. In a [pure setting](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pure_function), and leaving aside the specifics of Python (of which I know very little), a compiler might realize that both functions are identically `None`, and cause no calls to be made when the program is run. But a function that prints something (or inspects whether the current year is a leap year, or rolls a die) won't be pure.

Answer (score 2):

`zap = pants()` will bind the return value of the function to the variable, so of course the function is run if you bind it to a variable.

```
def foo():
    return 1

var = foo()
print var
```

will print `1`.

I hope this helps.

Edit: If you expect the value of the variable to be "put on some pants", you are indeed confusing `print` and `return`, as people pointed out in the comments.

Answer (score 1):

When the interpreter sees a function name followed by () it knows that it's supposed to execute that function.

What you're doing there is saying "assign the result of these functions to these variables".

But since you are not returning any values from those functions, you're not seeing anything in the variables.

However because you have a print statement in there, you are seeing the interpreter execute those functions as it attempts to assign the variable to results of that function.

Answer (score 0):

Your functions are called because of the parenthesis after the name:

```
zap = pants()
```

This calls the function pants and puts the result in zap.  If you had done this instead:

```
zap = pants
```

then zap would now refer to the pants function itself.

And if you just wrote

```
pants()
```

then the pants function would also get called, but the result (which is None) would never have been put in a variable.

Answer (score 0):

From your question what I think you want `zap` will have the value `"Put on some pants!"` and `thing` will have the value `"And don't forget your underwear!"`. If that is your problem let's discuss it. Otherwise you do not need to read further as I just discussed about all that.

Let's make it some fun. When you define a function, you are like creating a machine that does what you want it to do. Now let's think of a machine that when you give some food in it, it chops them and ... does nothing! I mean I made that machine to chop foods and nothing else! You won't get your chopped food back, but indeed it chopped your food as you made it for.

Now, as you want your chopped food back, you create another machine that takes your food, chops them and return them to you. Fruitful machine, isn't it? ;-)

They are all true for functions in programming or math (though I don't know any void function in math! :P). When you are creating the function, you have to tell it whether it just *does some work* or it *does some work and return the result*. The way to tell a function is the `return` statement. In your functions, you have just told to do something. And that is `print "......"` so does the functions. You call the with () at end and the does their work, they prints it. But as I said if you don't tell it to return a result, it won't. And because it is not returning any result, nothing will be assigned with the variable (don't confuse him with `None`). When you wrote those lines (if in interpreter) or run the script, you will see those lines printed but your `zap` and `thing` has no values.

So how to fix it? Tell them to return the lines to the variables. To tell the functions do that, replace the `print` statements with `return` statements. And never mind to experiment what you know, to know about what you know about your knowledge is true :-)

Hope it helps :-)